# A value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standards conversions to type C#

Tags: c#

"A value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standards conversions to type 'Reality.Game.Rooms.RoomActorType'" is there error I'm getting within my C#.exe.

The line(s) of error:

```
 public RoomActor GetActorByReferenceId(int ReferenceId, RoomActorType ReferenceType =    1)
    {
        lock (this.mActors)
        {
            foreach (RoomActor actor in this.mActors.Values)
            {
                if ((actor.Type == ReferenceType) && (actor.ReferenceId == ReferenceId)) /* line of error */
                {
                    return actor;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
   }
```

Here's Reality>Game>Rooms>RoomActorType.cs:

```
namespace Reality.Game.Rooms
{
using System;

public enum RoomActorType
  {
    AiBot = 2,
    UserCharacter = 1,
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Working fine here. Can you show exact line that compiler shows as error?

Comment: Can we have the class RoomActor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your method signature:

```
public RoomActor GetActorByReferenceId(int ReferenceId, RoomActorType ReferenceType = RoomActorType.UserCharacter)
```

Comment: It doesn't let me in the first 10 minutes, or I would.

Answer (score 1):

```
RoomActorType ReferenceType = 1)
```

should be

```
RoomActorType ReferenceType = RoomActorType.UserCharacter)
```

or if you really want to use int do:

```
RoomActorType ReferenceType = (RoomActorType)1)
```

You can not use int as enum without casting